# generate dynamic length arrays in c++ and accessing it in python using ctypes

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memory-management, ctypes

I am a novice at c++, currently trying to create a c extension to a python library using ctypes. My main issue is that I am generating two unknown lengthed vectors inside the c code and don't know the best way to initialize variables on the python code side to interface with the c code.

My approach is to initialize two double pointer float arrays on python side and point the vector data to them on the c side.

my_python_code.py:

```
float_ptr_ptr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))

# initialize the array getter function
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("my_c_lib.so")
dll.get_arrays.argtypes = [float_ptr_ptr, float_ptr_ptr]
dll.get_arrays.restype = ctypes.c_int

# initialize the function that deletes float array data
dll.delete_float_array.argtypes = [float_ptr_ptr]
dll.delete_float_array.restype = None

# initialize double pointer to float arrays
output_arr1_py = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)()
output_arr2_py = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)()

# call c function and save it to numpy arrays
vec_size = dll.get_arrays(ctypes.byref(output_arr1_py), ctypes.byref(output_arr2_py))
np_arr1 = np.fromiter(output_arr1_py, dtype=np.float, count=vec_size.value)
np_arr2 = np.fromiter(output_arr2_py, dtype=np.float, count=vec_size.value)

# deallocate float arrays in c
dll.delete_float_array(output_arr1_py)
dll.delete_float_array(output_arr2_py)
```

On c++ side I have a function `get_arrays()` that takes in two double-pointer to float array. `get_arrays` calls `set_vector_values` which populates two float vectors (`output_vec_1`, `output_vec_2`) and I want to then copy the data from `output_vec_1` to `output_arr_1` and `output_vec_2` to `output_arr_2`. I have two implementations:

my_c_lib.cc (implementation 1):

```
int get_arrays(float **output_arr_1, float **output_arr_2) {
    std::vector<float> output_vec_1; # same size as output_vec_2
    std::vector<float> output_vec_2;

    if (!set_vector_values(&output_vec_1, &output_vec_2)) {return -1; # if set_vector_values fails exit with retcode -1}
    *(output_arr_1) = output_vec_1.data();
    *(output_arr_2) = output_vec_2.data();
    return output_vec_1.size();
}
```

my_c_lib.cc (implementation 2):

```
int get_arrays(float **output_arr_1, float **output_arr_2) {
    std::vector<float> output_vec_1; # same size as output_vec_2
    std::vector<float> output_vec_2;

    if (!set_vector_values(&output_vec_1, &output_vec_2)) {return -1; # if set_vector_values fails exit with retcode -1}
    float *tmp1 = new float[output_vec_1.size()];
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < output_vec_1.size(); ++i) {
        tmp1[i] = output_vec_1[i];
    }

    float *tmp2 = new float[output_vec_2.size()];
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < output_vec_2.size(); ++i) {
        tmp2[i] = output_vec_2[i];
    }

    *(output_arr_1) = tmp1;
    *(output_arr_2) = tmp2;

    return output_vec_1.size();
  }

void delete_float_array(float **arr){
    delete[] *(arr);
 }
```

From my understanding c++ automatically handles memory de-allocation of vectors if I go out of scope how does this affect pointers to `vector.data()`? For implementation 1 for example, would `output_arr_1` still point to `output_vec_1.data()` or did that disappear once I move out of scope from `get_arrays`?

implementation 2 is me trying to deep copy the vector data into a temp float array so that output_arr_1 and _2 does not point to the vectors' data. once I am done with using the array I will then call `delete_float_array` to free up the array memory to prevent memory leak.

please let me know if there are better ways of doing what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: *"if I go out of scope how does this affect pointers to vector.data()" - if `vector` is declared in a scope eventually collapsing, then it no longer exists after that collapse, and thus all pointers and iterators referring to content of said-same are *invalid*. It's all about lifetime. If you need the lifetime to extend beyond the scope you have to provide a mechanism to do that. Your first implementation doesn't do that; your second does.

Comment: I'm just worries that memory management being the responsibility of the caller. It doesn't feel like it's a good practice

Comment: Have you considered using a framework like [Pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) instead of doing everything manually? Pybind11 has bindings between the C++ STL types and their Python/Numpy equivalents.

Comment: I will look into it but I would prefer to use ctypes since it's part of core python lib. Thank you for the rec.